# Email notification with weekly unanswered question on my favorites tags

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, email-notification

Recently I found useful to provided answers to unanswered questions, since I regularly search for a certain problem and get many related questions with no answer for a very long time.

Since Stackoverflow encourages users to help answer unanswered questions, It would be a great feature to receive once a week on my email a list of questions unanswered, thus easily providing answers.

This would allow the number of unanswered questions get reduced, helping those who work towards that goal to achieve it with less effort!

---

Kevin Reid, did suggest a better clarification of this feature goal, so:

Basically, grabbing the already existing [filters feature](https://stackexchange.com/filters/), it would gain an extra option at

*1. Which questions do you want to include?*:

- All Questions
- Just questions tagged with the _________ tag
- **Only Unanswered Questions tagged with the _________ tag** <sup>new</sup>

So we would have a weekly email with unanswered questions by tag!

Comment: These are the similar existing features, neither of which meets all of your requirements: The [weekly newsletter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/what-is-the-weekly-newsletter-who-composes-them) includes some unanswered questions, but is not specific to tags. The [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) feature can send weekly mail about new questions in a tag but does not allow selecting for unanswered questions. (I hope this clarifies the situation for other readers, or helps you refine your feature request.)

Comment: Kevin Reid, The question is quite clear, **weekly email with unanswered questions by tag!** I know about the mentioned features, but they aren't together on a specific goal like the proposed one! Don't really know how to improve or better clarify the question :/

Comment: [No moar emails!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iH7fe.png)

Comment: @The Establishment, Funny guy, but better to have an email per week, 4 per month, 48 per year, 4320 per lifespan, that going thru all the unanswered questions!

Comment: ...I disagree? I look through the unanswered questions frequently *when I want to look through them*. Why would I want someone emailing me *lists* of this stuff? Moreover, you can filter unanswered questions by tag or a number of other criteria in your searches, which should be sufficient in helping you to find questions you can answer.

Comment: The point is to free up some time to focus on the recent questions and deal with those who pass the net on a weekly basis, if not sooner! Because, man, we can't answer all, the proof is **236,812** with **no answers** (and counting)!