# How does the system select questions in the newsletter?

Tags: support, newsletter

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/what-is-the-weekly-newsletter-who-composes-them), we know that there are 3 sections in weekly newsletter and they are all automatically selected by the Stack Exchange system. How does the system select questions?

Answer (score 2):

From the [official announcement of the newsletters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters):

> - Hot questions for the week

- Random unanswered questions more than a few hours old and >0 score

*Hot questions for the week* most likely means the questions that appeared in the [Hot Network questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) during the last week.

As for exact amount of each can't really tell, but until official reply would be given, giving the best I can.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how the 2nd section generate which is "Greatest hits from previous weeks"?

Comment: Missed that part, also saw just now the sections in a Preview. Anyway not sure about the "Greatest hits from previous weeks", will try to dig around and make an educated guess when having some time.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to dig around too.